# BLOB file to display via a GUI

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012, blob

This is more of a, "hey, any ideas on how to go about doing this?", type of question.

So,

I'm working on a READ-ONLY GUI in Visual Studios, that loads data from an Oracle database. -- I am currently stumped on how to go about doing something: Loading an BLOB file from the oracle database and having it display via the GUI, so that the person reading it would be able to download said file by clicking a logo or text field or whatever works really. The person wouldn't be the ones uploading files; they should just be able to download them from what the GUI is pulling from the database.

Keep in mind, this file should not be limited to a single file type, should be able to upload .pdf, .txt, .wordx, .png, etc)... from Oracle, into Visual Studio.

I'm not sure which tool to use, nor the best way to go about this.

Tried looking it up, haven't really found any examples worth-mentioning or ideas pertaining to loading FROM Oracle into displaying for C#.

Any examples or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Developer offers this feature](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/10/sql-developer-blobs-and-the-external-editor/) - via Java. You asked about tools...

[image]

Comment: Not what I asked about - I already had the file saved into the blob, I asked how to go about loading it FROM Oracle to C#. - Figured this out already, in which, I figured out how to do yesterday. :D

Comment: your question was confusing, esp the 'from a GUI part' - not 'only using C code' - but glad you figured it out already